# php resize blob image

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I am echoing the data received from a blob column from mysql like this:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("mydb", $con);
  if(isset($_GET['imageid'])){
      $img=$_GET['imageid'];
      $sql="SELECT image FROM vrzgallery WHERE id=$img";
      $que=mysql_query($sql);
      $ar=mysql_fetch_assoc($que);
      echo $ar['image'];
      header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
  }

?>
```

**QUESTION**: How can i reduce my image to say like 500px X 500px

Comment: Surely the above is a typo, and you are calling `header()` before `echo $ar['image']` rather than after?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize images with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393319/resize-images-with-php)

Comment: Another example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551608/image-resize-with-php

Comment: @Michael its `header()` is after `echo` statement o.O

Comment: You must call `header()` before echoing out the image data: `header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); echo $ar['image'];`  Note also the correct header is `Content-type`

Comment: Your code is also vulnerable to SQL injection. You must validate or escape `$_GET['imgid']` before passing it to the query

Answer (score -1):

It is really the bad idea to store images in DB, because they are too big, harder to maintain, harder to work with and so on. You should store only path to it or file name.

To resize image you may use PHP's [GD](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) library. Create it using [`imagecreatefromstring()`](https://www.php.net/imagecreatefromstring) and manipulate using [`imagecopyresized()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php) or [`imagecopyresampled()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php). [Example from manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php):

```
// File and new size
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;

// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($thumb);
```